# Fill 2D Matrix depending on an ArrayList's objects coordinates

Tags: java

I have a 2D matrix of 10 rows and 10 columns, and an ArrayList containing objects having 4 parameters, 2 of these parameters being coordinates (float but always rounded).

```
// Create matrix
float [ ] [ ] grid = new float [ 10 ] [ 10 ];


public class MyObject {

  public float x;
  public float y;
  public int iD;
  public String myType;


  public MyObject (float x, float y, int iD, String myType) 
  {
    this.myType = myType;
    this.iD = iD;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[iD="+iD+" x="+x+" y="+y +" type="+myType+"]");
  }
}


ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

void setup() 
{
  size(100, 60);
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject(3.0, 4.0, 6, "a"));
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject(5.0, 2.0, 4, "b"));
}
```

I want to fill the matrix with 1 everywhere there is an object, but I can't manage to retrieve the first two parameters of my objects. For example, here I'd have a one at the position 3rd row and 4th column and at the position 5th row and 2nd column.

Is there a way to retrieve these 2 parameters and to add them to the right place in the matrix ? More objects could be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic flaw with your code.

**In java Real numbers are by default of type Double**

So floats are represented **by appending a f**

```
Float f=5.0f;
```

To do the task you asked you should perform the following loop.

```
for(MyObject o:myArrayList)
 grid[(int)o.x][(int)o.y]=1.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the arraylist like so:

```
for(MyObject current:myArrayList) {
  //Do anything you want to each object in the list
}
```

Your problem is due to the fact that you have coordinates that are floats and a 2d array.  You can do one of two things:

1. Change your x and y coordinates to be int.  Then you can refer directly to the array and use the x and y as indices to the array.  i.e. `grid[current.y][current.x]`
2. Otherwise you can cast the parameters, but that would leave the possibility of more than one item trying to occupy the same space.  For instance, 5.2 and 5.0 would both be position 5.  To be clear, you would do this by saying `grid[(int)current.y][(int)current.x];`

I think you may be confused in thinking that because you have a 2 dimensional float array you can store float indices.  But rather you have a 10x10 space for 100 float values.

```
x 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 * * * * * * * * * *
1 * * * * * * * * * *
2 * * * * * * * * * *
3 * * * * * * * * * *
4 * * * * * * * * * *
5 * * * * * * * * * *
6 * * * * * * * * * *
7 * * * * * * * * * *
8 * * * * * * * * * *
9 * * * * * * * * * *
```

As it is now though you can only put a single float value into that one particular place.  Not an object of the MyObject class.